# set song as alarm tone

Tags: alarm

How can I set song from my sd card as alarm tone ? i tried to change the tone but I cant figure out how to make the songs from my sd card to show up on the list.
I am using samsung galaxy ace with android 2.3.4

Comment: Did you try restarting your phone ?

Comment: Yes I restarted my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue with the Stock Alarm. Stock alarm was not able to recognize the SD Card songs. I vaguely remembered the solution. Couple of restarts and removing the SD Card from the phone and plugging it again solved the issue fro me.

But now I installed [Alarm Klock](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock) which has the option to see all the Songs on SD Card by Author and Album wise. It has vibrating feature which doesn't there in stock Alarm.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of apps that will let you set pretty much any sound file (mp3, ogg vorbis, etc) as a ringtone or notification sound.  [Tone Picker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hlidskialf.android.tonepicker&feature=search_result) is just one example.